# Error connecting to ami: Connection refused

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, freepbx

I am trying to connect remotely on my Free PBX AMI manager but I always receive an error of "Error connecting to ami: Connection refused"

I already configured my manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038
httptimeout = 60
bindaddr = 127.0.0.1
displayconnects=no ;only effects 1.6+

[myusername]
secret = mypassword
deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit= MY_SERVER_IP/255.255.255.0
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
writetimeout = 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bindaddr = 127.0.0.1
```

Mean you have no AMI on your external ip.

If you connecting to 127.0.0.1 -> you should allow 127.0.0.1. IF you connecting to external ip -> you have bind ami to that ip or 0.0.0.0